# Como posicionar o formulário no centro de uma DIV?

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
 background: #EFEFEF;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, "sans-serif;
}
.create-box{
 background: #DF5B5D;
 border: 10px dashed #FEFEFE;
 max-width: 550px;
 min-height: 88px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
}
.create-box form{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.create-box form input{
 display: block;
 margin: 5px 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #43A8C7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Trash [coder]</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="create-box">
   <form>
    <input type="text" id="titulo" placeholder="Digite o título" />
    <input type="text" id="conteudo" placeholder="Digite o conteúdo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Criar Boxer's" />
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Porque não consigo centralizar o formulário na DIV? oque está errado? solução?

Comment: Porque ele ocupa toda a largura da div.

Comment: Se eu removo ou altero a largura do .crate-box, ela também não posiciona..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta o seu problema é com essa margem

```
.create-box form input { margin: 5px 10px;}
```

Ela deveria ser assim:

```
.create-box form input { margin: 5px auto;}
```

Veja no Snippet como ficou com a alteração

```css
body{
 background: #EFEFEF;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, "sans-serif;
}
.create-box{
 background: #DF5B5D;
 border: 10px dashed #FEFEFE;
 max-width: 550px;
 min-height: 88px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
}
.create-box form{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.create-box form input{
 display: block;
 margin: 5px auto;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #43A8C7;
}
```

```html
<div class="create-box">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="titulo" placeholder="Digite o título" />
        <input type="text" id="conteudo" placeholder="Digite o conteúdo" />
        <input type="submit" value="Criar Boxer's" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: vaLew - Ajudou Muito